# How can I have a table with a set height but auto height cells

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
.suspensionTableScroll {
   width: 100%;
   height: 180px;
   overflow: auto;
}
```

I have the above CSS. the table is 180px which is good but the data inside it is not aligned to the top. rows are added in the middle with a large height that gets smaller as I add more rows.

How can I make their height auto depending on their content text?

I have tried `vertical-align:top` and `vertical-align:text-top` but the rows still appear in the middle

Comment: Maybe you want to set height of outer element in which you place the table instead?

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker are you psychic? that did the job.write it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want to set height of outer element in which you place the table instead?

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

table cell heights are adjusted automatically and dependent on the table height.

use [max-height](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-height.asp) instead of [height](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_height.asp), so table cell heights will be dependent on their contexts and your table height won't be more than 180px.